I need my FOR IF statement to check a range of cells for values
I have a FOR IF statement that I want to check a range of cells (5 cells per row) for any value. if any cell within that range has a value then another cell on the same row will have its value changed.
But I know i'm not going about this the right way. Can anyone help?
    'place rate type into callforward
 Dim r As Integer
     For r = 17 To 600
   If Cells("r", 14).Value <> "" Or Cells("r", 15).Value <> "" Or Cells("r", 16).Value <> "" Or Cells("r", 17).Value <> "" Or Cells("r", 18).Value <> "" Then
  Cells(r, 9).Value = "WKD"
   End If
   Next r


Change "r" to r for starters.

thank you BigBen that solved it. But is there a better way of doing it than having the 5 OR statements?

Perhaps WorksheetFunction.CountIfs.

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells(r, 14).Resize(, 5)) > 0 Then

For the shown task, you can do this without a loop at all by defining a range to have a formula and then converting the formula to its values. I also recommend using COUNTBLANK because both COUNTIF(S) and COUNTA will identify a cell that contains ="" as not blank (for example, if the cell contains a formula and the result is ""). I would consider that a blank cell and a cell you would not want to be counted as not blank per your posted code.
That all being said, something like this should work for you:
Sub tgr()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet:    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    With ws.Range("I17:I600")
        .Formula = "=IF(COUNTBLANK(N" & .Row & ":R" & .Row & ")<5,""WKD"","""")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    
End Sub


I already have a formula within the cells of column I which the code now removes  =IF(Y17="",,IF(AND(Y17>=TIMEVALUE("05:00"),Y17<=TIMEVALUE("18:59")),"MWD","MWN")) could this be incorporated into the VBA?

@MAXJebson In your original posted code, you were already overriding that. Do you mean that you want it to show WKD if there's a non-blank in N:R, but otherwise default to this formula?

If that's the case, you could just update your formula instead of using VBA: =IF(COUNTBLANK(N17:R17)<5,"WKD",IF(Y17="",,IF(AND(Y17>=TIMEVALUE("05:00"),Y17<=TIMEVALUE("18:59")),"MWD","MWN")))
